# Why not always use buffered streams?

Tags: performance

A buffered stream is better than a "normal" stream, because it makes less system calls, so most of the time it is faster. That argument is everywhere on the internet, but I can't find an example when a "normal" stream is better than a buffered one. Can someone explain or give an example when a "normal" stream is faster than a buffered one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of possible answers

- when it is buffered somewhere else.  Having multiple layers of buffering is inefficient and results in extra copying, not to mention extra calls
- when mis-ordering and/or loss is acceptable.  Sometimes you're dealing with a protocol where you don't care if data is lost as long as you have the latest.  Other times, you may be able to deal with misordering more efficiently without a buffer
- when doing things asynchronously.  Sometimes you want to react to the arrival of data ASAP rather than accumulating it in a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you turn off buffering when programs need to communicate with other programs. If the streams are buffered, the message never gets through and the system hangs waiting for a response which never comes.